# Range transformations with stateful lambdas and std::views::drop

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

it's my first time digging into the new `<ranges>` library and I tried a little experiment combining `std::views::transform` with a stateful lambda and 'piping' the resulting range to `std::views::drop`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto aggregator = [sum = 0](int val) mutable
                      {
                          return sum += val;
                      };

    vector<int> data{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    cout << "Expected:\n";
    int sum = 0;
    for (int val : data) {
        cout << (sum += val) << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "Transformation:\n- - - ";
    for (int val : data | views::transform(aggregator) | views::drop(3)) {
        cout << val << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The output was:

```
Expected:
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 
Transformation:
- - - 4 9 15 22 30 39 49
```

Now, the difference between each expected and actual output is 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. I am guessing it is a result of the lazy evaluation of ranges that causes `std::views::drop` to disregard the first three transformations.

Is there a way for me to force the evaluation of the `aggregator` functor for the three elements I drop? Or are stateful lambdas and ranges considered incompatible?

Comment: `views::transform` requires `F` must be [`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) (which guarantees *equality preservation*), which means that using state lambda will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @康桓瑋, that clears up the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform_view` is required to be a pure function. This is codified in [the `regular_invocable` concept](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.regularinvocable):

> The invoke function call expression shall be [equality-preserving](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concepts.equality) and shall not modify the function object or the arguments.

This is important to allow `transform_view` to not lie about its iterator status. Forward iterators, for example, are supposed to allow multipass iteration. This means that the value at each iterator position within the range must be independent of any other iterator position. That's not possible if the transformation functor is not pure.

Note that all [`predicate` functors](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.predicate) are also `regular_invocable`. So this also applies to things like `filter_view` and `take_while_view`.

Note that the algorithm `transform` does *not* have this requirement.

Comment: Any reason why they don't call it pure function instead of regular invocable? Maybe it's just me, but when I hear pure function I know instantly what that means; for regular invocable I have to look it up.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely answers my question. It's interesting that while `transform_view` must be a pure function, my compiler didn't warn me that it isn't.

Comment: @theejazz: Because your compiler can't tell whether it is a pure function or not.