# Generating unique random numbers with C++ ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I've been trying something just for fun but I stumbled upon a problem with the approach below. The thing is that I'm getting the value of zero twice in the generated range. What did I miss? Am I not using the ranges correctly or does it have something to do with the unordered_set?

```
    auto rng = 
    std::views::iota(0) | 
    std::views::transform([](size_t){ return rand() % 26; }) |
    std::views::filter([u = std::unordered_set<size_t>()](size_t i) mutable { return !u.emplace(i).second; }) |
    std::views::take(15);

    for (auto&& x : rng) { 
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Can't tell you what you did wrong but a very easy way to do this is to make an array/vector from the start of the range to the end of the range, [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) it, then take the first however many items needed.

Comment: The (possibly weird) idea in this piece of code was to use a particular seed with srand() function call to get a repeatable sequence of random numbers. I didn't specify that but it's a key requirement in a tiny experiment I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can do the same thing with `std::shuffle` since you can give it a random number generator set to whatever seed you want.

Comment: If you are after 15 numbers from 26 then the probability that they are all distinct is about 0.006. Just shuffle the numbers from 0 to 25 and take the first 15 of them.

Comment: @lastchance: The code is intended to take 15 *unique* numbers - the `take` is after the `filter`. This means the `transform` keeps calling `rand` until `filter` has passed 15 elements.

Comment: Related but not quite dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77708366/5754656 https://stackoverflow.com/q/71148130/5754656 https://stackoverflow.com/q/70418364/5754656

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::views::filter`'s predicate and `std::views::transform`'s transform function must be [`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable). In particular, this requires it to be equality preserving, meaning the callable can't be modified when it is called.

Your filter lambda doesn't meet this requirement since it calling it with the same number twice can lead to different results (`true` then `false`).

Your transform function doesn't either since it depends on the global state of `rand`. This is probably why you get the same number twice: the ranges algorithm expects `[](size_t){ return rand() % 26; }` to return the same thing given the same input, so it is called multiple times where it expects them to be the same. `operator++` will call it to get a number to test against the filter but `operator*` will call it again and give you a different number.

You can instead achieve this with a coroutine or writing a custom range with custom iterators. Or if you always have a fixed max number, the generate + shuffle algorithm suggested in the comments would work.