# I am unable to construct a vector using a iterators over a view that uses take_while in its construction

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, std-ranges, c++23

I ran into this problem while trying to make a powerset function using the std::views library.

```cpp
auto set = sv::repeat(0) 
    | sv::take_while([&mask](...) { return mask > 0; })
    | sv::transform([s, &mask, idx = 0](...) mutable { 
        return idx = std::countr_zero(mask & ~(mask - 1)), mask &= mask - 1, s[idx]; });
auto vec = std::vector(set.begin(), set.end());
           ^__________ ^______________________
"*cannot deduce types*"   "*no constructor found*" <- these are rough translations of verbose diagnostics
```

My question is, *why doesn't this work*? Normally I can construct vectors using views like this perfectly well, and I even do it later in the function.
I tested the same thing, but this time I used a captureless and const lambda:

```
auto arr = std::array {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3};
auto arr_view = arr | std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i < 4; });
auto vec = std::vector(arr_view.begin(), arr_view.end());
```

and got identical error messages.
Stranger still, I tried using the `std::ranges::move()` function to do the same thing, and it worked for some reason!
This code compiles and runs as expected (both with the constructed view as an rvalue and stored in a variable):

```
auto arr_view = arr | std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i < 4; });
auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
std::ranges::move(arr_view, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Initially, I thought this was because "arr_view" wasn't a sized range, but the same iterative approach of construction works for `std::views::filter()`, which is also not a sized range.
Can someone explain to me the reasoning behind this not working? Is it just me using (unstable) modern features?

Comment: Because `set.begin()` and `set.end()` returns different types of object, namely iterator and sentinel.

Comment: Side note : I think `std::generate` would be a better fit and will better describe the intent of what you are doing.

Comment: You can use `views::common` or just constructed `vector` via `ranges::to`. Try to find a duplicate of this.

Comment: @康桓瑋 `ranges::to` doesn't exist yet in  gcc 13.2, which is the compiler I use. Which compiler has it implemented? And thank you for recommending `views::common`, it worked!

Comment: I believe gcc-14 implemented `ranges::to`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 could you tell me where I can download it? I wasn't even aware gcc 14 existed for the public to use. I just looked at their site, the latest version I see for download is 13.2

Comment: Your first snippet has undefined behaviour btw. `take_while` and `transform` expect pure functions ([`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) functions that do not modify the function object). You may run into a problem where the functions are invoked multiple times unexpectedly, messing with the value of `mask` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70418364/5754656 )

Answer (score 7):

`set.begin()` and `set.end()` return iterators of different types, i.e. `begin()` returns an iterator while `end()` returns a sentinel. This is necessary for `take_while`, because one does not know beforehand how long to take. the sentinel returned by `end()` will compare equal to the iterator, once the predicate of `take_while` evaluates to false.

To construct a `std::vector` from a range with a sentinel there are different methods:

1. [`views::common`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_view) makes a view into a *common view* i.e. with different type iterators:

```
auto set1 = sv::iota(0)
    | sv::take_while([](auto counter) { return counter < 5; })
    | sv::common;
auto vec1 = std::vector(set.begin(), set1.end());
```

2. `std::vector`s new [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking a range. unfortunately, it needs a second argument to allow for the correct constructor to be chosen thus an object of `std::from_range_t` needs to be passed as the first argument.

```
auto set2 = sv::iota(0)
    | sv::take_while([](auto counter) { return counter < 5; });
auto vec2 = std::vector(std::from_range, set2);
```

3. using [`std::ranges::to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to) to convert a range to a container:

```
auto vec3 = sv::iota(0)
    | sv::take_while([](auto counter) { return counter < 5; })
    | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

[See Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PETMvjTG8)

**Note:** depending on your different methods might be implemented (e.g. in the demo clang trunk needs `-stdlib=libc++` to compile with its own standard library)